# Spring issues with JVM Arguments

Tags: spring, properties

I have a normal plain servlet . I am trying to load property file from the file system using Spring `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` class.The file location is supplied by the JVM arguments. The following is my declaration of my `MessageSource` bean

```
<bean id="xmlXpathProperties" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <!-- check property file(s) every 600 second(10min) -->
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="600"/>
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>file:#{systemProperties.aircdrconfig}/cdr-airxml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
/bean>
```

If i am giving the JVM argument name with any special characters such as dots(.) or hyphen(-) for example : `air.cdr.config`, I am getting an exception like.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException Field or property 'air' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties'
```

If i remove the dot symbol then it's working fine. Any idea to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to refer to the properties this way:

```
#{ systemProperties['air.cdr.config'] }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. Now its working fine.Once again thanks a lot